Why am I getting Negative Marginal Effects for Coefficients that are Positive?
I've run a hurdle Poisson model in R on the pscl package and used the marginaleffects package for the marginals and I'm getting negative margins for coefficients that are positive, even those greater than 1, on the logit part of the model.
Here is the code I'm using:
library(pscl)
library(marginaleffects)
data(quine, package = "MASS")
PoissonHurdle_model <- hurdle(Days ~ Eth + Sex + Age + Lrn,
                              data = quine, dist = "poisson")

avg_slopes(PoissonHurdle_model, type = "response")

avg_slopes(PoissonHurdle_model, type = "zero")


We may be better able to help you if you could edit your post to include a Minimal (!) Working (!) Example. See How to make a great R reproducible example.

Thank you @StephanKolassa, I've added an example.

That does not work as you have not included selected_data_clean or the outputs to illustrate your question

In your example, all the slopes have the same sign as the corresponding coefficients.

@Vincent yes, the issue is perculiar to my data and only on the logit part of the model. It seems counterintuitive and I'm looking for posssible explanations.
